# ssdt dacpac: how to prevent dacpac to generate the error when dropping columns in a table with data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I am dropping a column in a table `xxx` with data. The DACPAC is generating the checking as follow.

```
IF EXISTS (select top 1 1 from [dbo].[xxx])
    RAISERROR (N'Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss might occur.', 16, 127) WITH NOWAIT
```

All the data migration has been done in pre-deployment script. Currently I have comment it out manually.

How to prevent it from auto generating?

Comment: what exactly you need is not cleare..

Comment: i'd like the dacpac to drop the column without checking if the data is existing in this table or not.

Answer (score 5):

for those who use sqlpackage to deploy dacpac or use Azure devops set the following in additional arguments and it should work.

```
/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False
```

Answer (score 3):

Uncheck `Block incremental deployment if data loss might occurred` in VS\Publish\Advanced\General.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is most likely due to a dependency like a trigger.

If you aren't sure what object is causing it, you can use the following script to identify

```
select * from sys.objects
where Object_id = (OBJECT_ID('<name of object blocking'))
```